# How to define a request timeout on asp.net core MVC on linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Given:

- ASP.Net Core MVC application, deployed in docker containers on linux.
- Nginx reverse proxy + load balancer

When the ASP.Net core container gets stuck (after a timeout on nginx), it calls a different instance of the application. At that point, the application should cancel the processing in order to not perform data manipulation operations twice. This works great with a global:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    using (context.HttpContext.RequestAborted.Register(() => context.HttpContext.RequestAborted.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()))
    {
        await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```

The problem here is, that nginx might cancel the request, right after the transaction in the controller and underlying services completed. Which means, the request was successful, but just slightly too long, and nginx will try a second time anyway. In order to solve this, we wanted to set a second timeout which would be few seconds shorter than nginx timeout. The only solution I've found is this:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var timeout = new CancellationTokenSource();

    timeout.CancelAfter(ActionTimeout);

    using (timeout.Token.Register(() => timeout.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()))
    using (context.HttpContext.RequestAborted.Register(() => context.HttpContext.RequestAborted.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()))
    {
        await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```

But this is throwing the following exception:

```
System.AggregateException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Additional information: One or more errors occurred.
```

And afterwards the application is crashing. Putting try/catch anywhere around of course also doesn't help and adding a global exception filter to the middleware doesn't help either.

What is the best way to cancel Requests on linux after a custom timout, without depending on a reverse proxy to do it?

**Update - details on exceptions:**

At first I see the following exception:

```
System.OperationCanceledException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233029
  Message=The operation was canceled.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
       at ...BaseController.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<OnActionExecutionAsync>b__0() in ...\Controllers\BaseController.cs:line 28
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  InnerException:
```

Which is fine, that's the cancellation token throwing the exception. But the second one, the one which I can't catch, not sure how I could see the details there, I just see the following screen:

[image: Exception Screenshot]

And regardless of what I tried, the process always stopped afterwards (even if I press continue execution)

Comment: What are the individual exceptions in the aggregate exception?

Comment: @JasonSturges I don't know how to figure that out. I've updated my question with more details.